# error 500 al hacer peticion de imagen a servidor

Tags: imagen, servidor

tengo una pagina donde un icono no se carga, sale el en lace roto, revisa la consola de errores del navegador en la pestaña red me aparece el estado error 500, reviso la url a la que hace referencia y todo esta correcto, estoy trabajando con la plataforma chamilo, alguna idea? dejo una imagen del erorr que me muestra en la consola:

[image]

Comment: ¿Que error te da en el log del servidor?

Comment: Donde puedo ver los errores que se generan al momento que se carga la pagina? porque dentro de la carpeta donde se encuentra la pagina hay un archivo error.log pero si lo abro no me aparecen errores de hoy ni de el momento en que ejecuto la pagina, es decir, no me muestra los errores que general al cargar la pagina.

Comment: este es uno:  [Fri Mar 22 13:56:29.165023 2019] [cgid:error] [pid 26535:tid 140034407614208] [client 201.249.27.14:15700] AH01271: exec used but not allowed in /home/seaconfi/public_html/e-learning/500.shtml, referer: https://e-learning.seaconfiable.com/main/course_home/course_home.php?cidReq=SEA01&id_session=0&gidReq=0&gradebook=0&origin=&intro_cmdEdit=1

Comment: ¿Cómo está escrita la URL de la petición? ¿Tu sitio funciona bien en navegación normal? El error *`exec used but not allowed`* me parece que se refiere a Apache.

Comment: esta escrita de la misma forma que aparece ahi en la referencia. la pagina carga bien, pero las imagenes no se muestran.

Comment: tambien tengo estos errores en el .htaccess, pero las urls estan bien escritas. . RewriteBase: argument is not a valid URL, referer:

Comment: Tiene la carpeta dónde están la imagines el modo rx para el usario del servicio Apache?

Comment: si amigo, de hecho le di permisos 777 para probar solamente y nada, es lo hice desde el cpanel, en la opcion cambiar permisos.